# How to switch values in a list to print an alternated version of the list?

Tags: list, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to switch numbers in a long list.

For example if were to have a list:

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

and wanted to instead print it in the form of:

```
numbers_2 = [2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7]
```

such that each pair would be switched, using a for-loop. I thought about doing something like:

```
for i in range(0, len(numbers), 2):
```

But wasn't really able to get much further.

Comment: Print it that way, or actually rearrange it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop every second index and swap two adjacent items:

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
for i in range(1, len(numbers), 2):
    numbers[i-1], numbers[i] = numbers[i], numbers[i-1]
```

Not sure about the other answers, but this one will also work with a list of an uneven length, and leave the last item untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def swap_array_elements (a):
    for i in range (0, len(a) - 1, 2):
        a[i], a[i +1] = a[i + 1], a[i]
    return a

a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print (swap_array_elements (a))
# prints: [1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 9, 8]
```

Comment: python lets you write nicer swap code than that: `a[i], a[i+1] = a[i+1], a[i]`

Comment: and also nicer loops: `for i in range(0, len(a), 2):`

Answer (score 0):

Take 2 halves, and rearrange them:

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] 
first = numbers[::2]
second = numbers[1::2]
numbers_2 = sum(map(list, zip(second, first)), [])
```

Comment: Taking every-other element into two lists (odds and evens) and then zipping them... clever. But won't this drop the last item in the list if the list length is uneven?

Comment: this leaves out the last number when for example  `numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] `

Comment: @mkj the behavior for this case is not specified in the question.

Comment: Fair enough. Maybe it should just be an error with the current specification